# retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 5

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Here is the code to delete the data

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (findViewById(R.id.btnDelete)==v){
        restService.getService().deleteEmpById(_Student_Id, new Callback<AC_Daily_Line>() {
            @Override
            public void success(AC_Daily_Line spsTrans, Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(AttendanceDelete.this, "Employee Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AttendanceDelete.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });
```

Here is the JSON data

{"ID":2603,"AC_ID":"210924-0828","Emp_ID":"123456789","Att_Date":"2021-09-24T08:50:00"}

Here is my data class

```
public class AC_Daily_Line {

    public int ID;
    public String AC_ID;
    public String Emp_ID;
    public String Att_Date;
}
```

Here is my calling path to Web API

```
    @DELETE("/api/AC_Daily_Line/{id}")
    public void deleteEmpById(@Path("id") Integer id,Callback<AC_Daily_Line> callback);
```

Comment: Where is your data class/pojo class??

Comment: @UmeshYadav oh, now I have update my data class

Comment: And it's helpful to follow best practices especially regarding naming convention. ```Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).```. From : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using wrong type for storing your id variable. In your POJO class, ID is an int, while when retrieving data from your API, you're passing ID as Integer.

Note that there is a difference between `int` and `Integer`. int is a primitive data type while Integer is a Wrapper class. One is a primitive type while the other being a class